# Ubuntu directory permissions - Sticky bit - Prevent deletion of a file

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, files

I have a database called `oss-pwds.kdb` located in a folder `/keepassx`.  This is a password database that I use with the KeePassX software.  I want to allow all members of the "oss" group to open and modify the database, but not to inadvertently delete it.

Here is what I have:

```
groupadd oss
chgrp oss /keepassx
chown root /keepassx
chown root /keepassx/oss-pwds.kdb
chmod 1770 /keepassx
chmod 1770 /keepassx/oss-pwds.kdb
```

At first, it looks like this should work.  However, if I open the database in the KeePassX software, make a change, then try to save it, a `.tmp` file appears in the `/keepassx` directory and I get an error upon saving: "File could not be saved. The file could not be removed."

How do I prevent deletion of *only* the `oss-pwds.kdb` file but allow deletion of other files in the `/keepassx` directory such as the `.tmp` file?

Comment: What are the user/group ownership of the file? and what UID does process run under?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869536/linux-directory-permissions-read-write-but-not-delete

Comment: @slm Looks like ACLs are the best way to go here.

Comment: @gertvdijk - agreed. This topic has been covered on most of the SE sites.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/326873/how-to-lock-a-file-against-deletion-but-still-make-it-writeable